# is VAR |= 1 << 2; reverisble?

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, bit-manipulation

First I am not sure what is going on in this bitwise operation.
I get code written and supply to other parties as code snippets.

Now if VAR is unsigned 8bit integer (unsigned char) and r is either 0 or 1 or 2 or 4.
Can following be reversed if the value of r is known and resulting value is there.
**VAR |= 1 << r;** //that is 200 where VAR was 192 and r was 3

For example initial value of **VAR is 192** and value of **r is 3** **result is 200**.

Now if **I have this 200**, and I **know the value of r** that was 3, **can I reverse it back to 192 ?**

I hope it is most easy one, but I don't know these bitwise operations, so forgive me.

Thanks

Comment: No. A bit value of 1 could've been produced from either `0 | 1` or `1 | 1`.

Comment: Makes sense, and even VAR <<= 3; cannot be reversed? I dont know what I am asking but it is part of question.

Comment: @Jasonz That's correct. Because you don't know the bits that have been shifted off. Whenever multiple inputs can result in the same output, then the function is not invertible.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer is no. This is because the `|` (OR) operator is not a [one-to-one function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function).

In other words, there are multiple values of `VAR` that can produce the same result.

For example:

```
r = 3;
var0 = 8;
var1 = 0;

var0 |= 1 << r;  //  produces 8
var1 |= 1 << r;  //  produces 8
```

If you tried to invert it, you wouldn't be able to tell whether the original value is `0` or `8`.

A similar situation applies to the `&` AND operator.

---

**From an information-theory perspective:**

The operators `|` and `&` incur a ***loss of information*** and do not preserve the entropy of the data.

On the other hand, operators such as `^` (XOR), `+`, and `-` are one-to-one and thus preserve entropy and are invertible.

Comment: That one-to-one function reference paints a pretty good picture.

Comment: Depending on the situation, that can be true. Signed integer overflow is undefined behavior. But if we assume unsigned integers, then `+` and `-` can be inverted even with overflow. For example: `0xffffffff + 1 = 0` Inverting is `0 - 1 = 0xffffffff`.

Answer (score 6):

No, `OR` is not reversable.  I believe only `XOR` is.

For example, if variable `a` contains `1001 1100` or `1001 1000`, and you set the third bit (from the right) to `1` regardless of what the initial value is, then both `1001 1100` and `1001 1000` as source operands would result in the same value (`1001 1100`).

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, 1<<2 is just another way of writing "4" or 100 in binary.

The |= operator is another way of writing x = x | y;

The end result is setting bit 2 in x. If bit 2 in x was zero then reversing it would be to clear bit 2. If bit 2 was 1, then it's a no-op.

The problem with your question is that you don't know ahead of time what the initial state of bit 2 was.

If your goal was to clear bit 2 you can do this:

```
x &= ~(1<<2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Given an expression `result |= 1 << shiftAmount`, corresponding to VAR and r in your original example, you can use the following to do the exact opposite:

```
result &= ~(1 << shiftAmount)
```

Note that this is not a pure inverse, because bitwise-or is not a one-to-one function. Bitwise-or sets one or more bits to 1, whether or not they were already 0 or 1. The expression I have shown above will always set the associated bits to 0, so if the bit was 1 originally it will not go back to its original state.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't reverse an OR operation.

In your example, with r=3, both the starting values VAR=192 and VAR=200 will result in 200.

Since there are two input values that will give the same result, you won't know which one to go back to.